# Creating threads on a loop

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm new to threading, so I want to understand what is happening behind the scenes when you create a bunch of `Thread`s in a loop and the implications/better ways of doing it.

Here's an example:

```
for (Page page : book) {
    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            //http request to get page and put into concurrent data structure
        }
    });
    t.start();
    threads.add(t);
}
//wait for threads
```

As you can probably see, in my specific use case right now, I am paging through objects that I request via HTTP. I know there doesn't necessarily need to be threads here and instead I could make async requests, but how (with explanations) how this could be improved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example your are creating and starting a new thread for each `Page` object you have in your book. This is not useful if you have many more pages than cores on your system.

It's also kinda low-level by now to directly create and start threads and keep track of them.

A better solution would be to use an `ExecutorService` and create a number of threads close, for example, to the number of cores there is on the system (for I/O bound tasks you may want to create more threads than that: you can check out the comments below this answer).

For example:

```
final ExecutorService e = 
    Executors.newFixedThreadPool(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors());

for (Page page : book) {
    e.submit( new Runnable() {
              //http request to get page and put into concurrent data structure}
}
```

You'd then wait on your `ExecutorService` to terminate its job.

Note that depending on the server you're fetching your information from, you may need to add, on purpose, delays as to not "hammer" the server too much.

Certain websites will tell you how often you can query them (for example the Bitstamp bitcoin exchange allows one query per second) and will ban your IP if you don't respect the delay. Others won't well you anything and simply ban your IP if they detect that you're leeching too fast.

Comment: 'This is not going to be efficient if you have many more pages than cores on your system.' - you are aware that the threads are probably going to be network-bound and blocked most of the time?

Comment: yes, but i wanted to understand how to use threads better (as i said in my post, i would rather solve this specific problem with async requests but it got me thinking about how to more effectively manage threads in java).

Comment: @Martin James: sure but if OP has 5000 pages in its book there's not much point in creating 5000 threads *"because they're probably going to be network-bound"*. Using an *ExecutorService* and a fixed thread pool with a size close to the number of cores is "good practice". Spawning countless threads isn't. Edited the answer a bit.

Comment: I think his point (and I concur) is that if you want to keep an N-core  cpu busy (i.e. maximize throughput) you want the number of *total* threads, T, to be sufficiently large that, statistically speaking, the number of *running* threads is close to N. And if you have a lot of network-bound threads that spend a lot of time blocked, you need to make T >> N.

Comment: @JVMATL: ok sure but here OP is talking about fetching "pages" from a "book server".  I guess it's a unique server. It's not the same as in writing a web crawler that would fetch, in parallel, webpages from totally unrelated sites. But, sure, OP may want to experiment and make T > N if it gives him better throughput...

Comment: @TacticalCoder I totally agree about wanting to limit the total number of threads to something sane, for various reasons you point out. I mostly wanted to correct the assertion that keeping the thread pool size the same os the number of cores was "good practice" -- it *is* good practice for computationally intensive workloads, but it may be significantly undersized for other kinds of IO-bound tasks.